# Если больше людей с одного роутера заходят на сайт, превышается время ожидания ответа

Tags: php, ajax, router

Если больше людей с одного роутера заходят на сайт, превышается время ожидания ответа и как результат теряют соединение.

В чём может быть проблема?
Ошибку броузер выдаёт (превышено время ожидания от сервера)

- Сайт работает отлично, проблема появляется только когда больше 5-8
  человек начинают с ним работать.

  2. Написан на PHP, все запросы уходят через AJAX...
  3. Tracert делали (при проявлении данной ошибки), задержка только в начале т.е. когда нажимается кнопка и отправляется запрос... после
     чего всё начинает работать нормально...
  4. С Тех Поддержкой сервера связались... проблему там не нашли
  5. С интернет-провайдером связывались... проблему там тоже не нашли

Помогите пожалуйста, не знаю где копать...
Пример JS-AJAX

```
     $(document).on("change","#section select", function() 
     {checkStreet();showCreatePeopleCardButton();})
      function openPeopleSondaj(id){
      $.ajax({
                   url: "api/opensondaj.php",
                   type: "POST",
                   data: ({
                        sondaj : id
                    }), 
                   success: function(data){
                        $("#sondaj").css('top', 
       ($(window).scrollTop()+100)+"px");
                        $("#sondaj").removeClass("hidden");
                        $("#sondaj").append(data); 
                    },
                }); 
     }

     function checkStreet(){
     var section = $("#section select").val();
     $.ajax({
                   url: "api/filter.php",
                   type: "POST",
                   data: ({
                        section : section
                    }), 
                   success: function(data){
                        showStreet(data);

                    },

                });
    }
```

Пример PHP

```
                <?php
                session_start();
                if(isset($_POST['section'])){

                    $section = $_POST['section'];
                    $_SESSION['section'] = $section;
                    require_once 'db/con.php'; // подключаем скрипт
                    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)or die("Ошибка ".mysqli_error($link));
                    mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM section_street WHERE section = '{$section}' ORDER BY `street`";

                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
                    $arr = "<option></option>";
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $arr .= "<option street='{$row['street']}' house='{$row['house']}'>{$row['street']} {$row['house']}</option>";  
                    }

                    echo $arr;

                }
                else if(isset($_POST['street'])&&isset($_POST['house'])){

                    if(isset($_POST["tel_num"])&&$_POST["tel_num"]=="true"){$tel_num = "AND ((LENGTH(`mob_gsm`)>1) OR (LENGTH(`fix_gsm`)>1))";}else{$tel_num = "";}

                    $street = $_POST['street'];
                    $house = $_POST['house'];
                    $_SESSION['street'] = $street;
                    $_SESSION['house'] = $house;
                    require_once 'db/con.php'; // подключаем скрипт
                    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)or die("Ошибка ".mysqli_error($link));
                    mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM peoples WHERE street = '{$street}' AND house = '{$house}'".$tel_num." ORDER BY street,house,housing,apartment";
                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

                    if($_SESSION["work"]=="bigboss"||$_SESSION["work"]=="boss"){
                        $arr = "<table id='2excel'><tr><td style='width: 200px;'>Adresa</td><td>Nume, Prenume</td><td>Atingeri</td><td style='width: 60px;'>Actiuni</td></tr>";
                    }elseif($_SESSION["work"]=="manager"||$_SESSION["work"]=="agitator"){
                        $arr = "<div id='export-btn'>Export</div><table id='2excel'><tr><td style='width: 200px;'>Adresa</td><td>Nume, Prenume</td><td class='hidden'>Social</td><td class='hidden'>Plecati</td><td class='hidden'>Indispusi</td><td style='width: 180px;' class='noExl'>Actiuni</td></tr>";
                    }else{
                        $arr = "<table id='2excel'><tr><td style='width: 200px;'>Adresa</td><td>Nume, Prenume</td><td style='width: 180px;'>Actiuni</td></tr>";
                    }

                    $adress ="";
                    $class="";
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $adress = " casa: ".$row['house'];
                        if($row['housing']!="")$adress.="/".$row['housing'];
                        if($row['apartment']!="")$adress.=" ap. ".$row['apartment'];
                        IF($row['mob_gsm']!=""||$row['fix_gsm']!=""){

                            $replace = array(' ','-');
                            $mob = $row['mob_gsm']==""?".":substr(str_replace($replace,'',str_replace('+373','0',$row['mob_gsm'])),0,9);
                            $fix = $row['fix_gsm']==""?".":substr(str_replace($replace,'',str_replace('+373','0',$row['fix_gsm'])),0,9);

                            $class = "green";
                            $sql_calls = "SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `calls` WHERE (`phone`='{$mob}' OR `phone`='{$fix}') AND `dialog_time_sec`>0";
                            $result_calls = mysqli_query($link, $sql_calls);
                            $row_calls = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_calls);
                            if($row_calls['COUNT(`id`)']>0){
                                $calls = "<div class='calls'><div class='calls_text'>".$row_calls['COUNT(`id`)']."</div></div>";
                            }

                            $sql_missed_calls = "SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `calls` WHERE (`phone`='{$mob}' OR `phone`='{$fix}') AND `dialog_time_sec`=0";
                            $result_missed_calls = mysqli_query($link, $sql_missed_calls);
                            $row_missed_calls = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_missed_calls);
                                if($row_missed_calls['COUNT(`id`)']>0){
                                    $calls .= "<div class='missed_calls'><div class='calls_text'>".$row_missed_calls['COUNT(`id`)']."</div></div>"; 
                                }else{
                                    $calls .= "";
                                }
                            $sql_sondaje = "SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `sondaj_peoples_results` WHERE `people_id`='{$row['id']}' AND `sondaj_item_id`!=0";
                            $result_sondaje = mysqli_query($link, $sql_sondaje);
                            $row_sondaje = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_sondaje);
                                if($row_sondaje['COUNT(`id`)']>0){
                                    $calls .= "<div class='done_sondaje'><div class='calls_text'>".$row_sondaje['COUNT(`id`)']."</div></div>"; 
                                }else{
                                    $calls .= "";
                                }




                        }else{
                            $class = "class='empty'";
                            $calls = "";
                            }
                        if($row['bussy']=="da"){$class=" red";}
                        if($row['plecat']=="da"){$class=" white";}
                        if($_SESSION["work"]=="bigboss"||$_SESSION["work"]=="boss"){
                            $arr .= "<tr class='{$class}'><td>{$adress}</td><td>{$row['name']} {$row['surname']} </td><td>{$calls}</td><td><div class='inline view' id='{$row['id']}'></div></td></tr>"; 
                        }elseif($_SESSION["work"]=="manager"||$_SESSION["work"]=="agitator"){
                            $arr .= "<tr class=' {$class}'><td>{$adress}</td><td>{$row['name']} {$row['surname']} </td><td class='hidden'>{$row['social']}</td><td class='hidden'>{$row['plecat']}</td><td class='hidden'>{$row['bussy']}</td><td class='noExl'><div class='inline sondaj_action' id='{$row['id']}'></div><div class='inline action' id='{$row['id']}'></div></td></tr>";    
                        }else{
                            $arr .= "<tr class=' {$class}'><td>{$adress}</td> 
    <td>{$row['name']} {$row['surname']} </td><td><div class='inline 
    sondaj_action' id='{$row['id']}'></div><div class='inline action' 
    id='{$row['id']}'></div></td></tr>";    
                        } 
                        $calls = "";
                    }
                    $arr.="</table>";


                    echo $arr;
                }
                else{
                    echo "Access forbiden.";
                }

                ?>


Прошу не судите строго(стиль программирования), опыта у меня не много ...
```

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под роутером? Вы имете ввиду программу которая выдает страничку в зависимости от URL, или физический роутер?

Comment: + Покажите код ваших запросов, и php тоже, иначе не понятно как вам будут помогать.

Comment: Спасибо за отзывчивость,  сделал правку - добавил 1 пример и JS+AJAX и PHP

Comment: Роутер имею в веду физический...

Comment: запросы в циклах это очень плохая идея

Comment: Про какой запрос имеете в веду? я старался их в цикл не сувать....

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть что в базе просиходит в моменты зависания, выполнив запрос "show processlist;". COUNT очень дорогая функция.

Comment: дело в том что происходит ошибка только когда сеть в офисе перегружена... для тех кто работают по 1 или 2 с одного интернета проблем нет вообще...

Comment: но всё таки попробую